# c# console application .netcore 3.0 sqlite-net-pcl | Unable to add rows

Tags: c#, sqlite-net-pcl

I am using: c# console application .netcore 3.0 sqlite-net-pcl and I am unable to add rows to a table from consecutive insert operations.  If I step through a debug, the table will populate partially.

```
foreach (Trivia t in trivias){triviaDBHardKey.HardKeyTrivia(t);}

public async void HardKeyTrivia(Trivia trivia
    {awaitProgram.Database.SaveTriviaAsync(trivia));}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite-net-pcl SaveTriviaAsync command works with Xamarin, so I assume it is not useful for c#-app-console.  My issue now is how to clear the database and re-populate it and once re-populated; view it on a list view.  I am able to delete it and re-populate it on two emulation starts, however, how to do this with one session is beyond me.